# Convert list of string to DataTable

Tags: c#

I want to convert List of string to datatable so I try:

```
List<string> DesignNameList = new List<string>();

  public static Mymethod...{

     parameters = ToDataTable(DesignNameList);
   }


 public static DataTable ToDataTable(List<string> list)
        {

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dataTable;

        }
```

But I get error when foreach is being executed in line `dataTable.Rows.Add(row);`:

> 'Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'

What I'm doing wrong? Regards

Comment: There is little reason to do such a thing.  A List<T> is probably a bit more flexible than a DT...and you certainly do not need a DataTable you created for DB updates

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add a column to the data table first. As it is created is has no columns

```cs
DataTable datatable= new DataTable();  

DataColumn workCol = datatable.Columns.Add("column_name", typeof(String));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to exchange the loop 'foreach' by the 'for', like this:

```
  DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
  {
      dataTable.Rows.Add(list[i]);
  }
  return dataTable;
```

Comment: How will that make any difference given the error message?